# VS2017 command line build (missing "%VS150COMNTOOLS%VSVars32.bat")

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have installed VS2017 and call

```
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%VSVars32.bat"
```

from the command line but all I get is

```
'"%VS150COMNTOOLS%VSVars32.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

If I run "set" from the command line I can see VS120COMNTOOLS (for VS2013) & VS140COMNTOOLS (for VS2015) but there is no VS150COMNTOOLS. How can I build from the command line?

Answer (score 8):

I submitted this as a tech support issue to Microsoft who accepted it as a bug in the install ("there is no VSVars32.bat in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools` directory.").

However, there is a work-around:

From MS:

> At least, since there is a VsDevCmd.bat, there is a Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt, which also sets, modifies environment variables (Framework40Verion, FrameworkDir, FrameworkDIR64, FrameworkVersion, FrameworkVersion64, INCLUDE, IPCPATH, PATH, VCINSTALLDIR, VCToolsInstallDir, ...)
>   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\EDITION\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`
>
> Run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\EDITION\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` where `EDITION` is the type of VS2017 install, i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` for the Enterprise install. This sets up the needed environment variables and batch builds will work.

Hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Note there's also C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat and companions

Comment: Thanks - not present for the enterprise install. Well, not there on mine anyway.

Comment: hmm I don't have VS2017 on this machine so I might be wrong. Could also be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build or so.

Answer (score 2):

VS2017 has reworked its directory structure and filenames. The file is no longer titled "VsVars32.bat", you should look for the file '**vcvars.bat**', which can be located in  `..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\EDITION\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext\vcvars.bat` (using Adam's syntax, replace `EDITION` with the version of Visual Studio you use).

For simplicity, you can use `%VSAPPIDDIR%` in your call to point to the IDE folder where devenv.exe is located, and go back one folder to define your path to the batch file. For example:

```
call "%VSAPPIDDIR%..\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext\vcvars.bat"
```

Comment: For VS 2019 it's now at `..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\EDITION\VC\Auxiliary\Build\`

Answer (score 1):

If its any help to anyone...
If you modify your Visual Studio 2017 installation to install the component:
"VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset for Desktop (x86,x64)"

then the 'VSVars32.bat' file which is missing, will be installed (as its a component of VC++ 2015, but not VC++ 2017).

Comment: I can't find an equivalent for this with VS 2019, either the BuildTools or Community. They may have renamed the component to no longer include the word "toolset" though?